# Django - Haystack in two differents apps

Tags: django-haystack

I am using Haystack in one app and its perfect. It is indexing everything that I need. But, now I created another app, with different model and content, and I would like to Haystack index it. The idea is to create two different "search" links on my website, one for each app.

However, when I add the second configuration to haystack index it, I get some problem...

I created a new search_index.py (inside my new app) with the following content:

```
import datetime
from haystack.indexes import *
from haystack import site
from oportunity.models import Oportunity


class OportunityIndex(SearchIndex):
    title = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    body = CharField()
    date= DateTimeField()

    def index_queryset(self):
        return Oportunity.objects.filter(date=datetime.datetime.now())


site.register(Oportunity, OportunityIndex)
```

but, when I run python manage.py rebuild_index
I get the following error:

> line 94, in all_searchfields
>       raise SearchFieldError("All SearchIndex fields with 'document=True' must use the same fieldname.")
>   haystack.exceptions.SearchFieldError: All SearchIndex fields with
>   'document=True' must use the same fieldname.

Comment: Could you try after removing from haystack.indexes import *, and doing a qualified import? I once ran into such a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known limitation of Haystack which has been discussed in a [few different places](http://unfoldthat.com/2011/05/04/you-should-use-django-haystack-like-this.html) where the underlying document store needs the document field to be consistently named across all search models.

It is [documented in the haystack docs](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/en/latest/searchfield_api.html#document) what the recommended document field name is.  Bottom line, you can't define `title = CharField(document=True)` on one index and `content = CharField(document=True)` on another index, they have to be named the same.

BEST PRACTICE: name the index field `text`. This is [recommended by the haystack docs](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html#significance-of-document-true) and will give you the most compatibility with 3rd party apps.